# Create the smallest possible git repository

Tags: git

I am going to create tons of small git repositories, and I am trying to avoid wasting precious space with `hooks`, `info`, etc directories.

I know that it is possible to point to an empty template directory using

`git-init --template`

but is there a way to not being forced to specify the directory? Oddly enough `--no-template` is considered a valid argument, but it will just use the default template.

Also, is there a way to prevent git to add `.git/logs`?

Comment: May be just put inactive repositories to archive (for example by keeping only .git/objects/pack/pack-whatever.pack for them)?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the most sensible solution. I just wondered if there was a way to tell git to do it for me.

Comment: It's not hard to work it out.  `mkdir -p .git/{refs,objects}; echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD; git config core.repositoryformatversion 0` and you're done.  gotta chime in with the wtf? crowd: every use I can think of, if the template space is even a rounding error on your repo space why do you need git?  there's also a config option to not log ref updates.

Comment: To answer your wtf? question, the advantage I get in using git (even on really small repos) is that I can track all changes to my files really easily and roll back if necessary. There's much more than that, but this is the reason in a nutshell.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following size measures, you'd only need to delete the .git/hooks/* files to achieve a notably small .git repository.  Fortunately, it is completely safe to delete hooks (no hook; no action).

```
ebg@taiyo(509)$ du -sh foo/.git
 52K    foo/.git
ebg@taiyo(510)$ du -sh foo/.git/*
  4K    foo/.git/HEAD
  0B    foo/.git/branches
  4K    foo/.git/config
  4K    foo/.git/description
 36K   foo/.git/hooks
  4K    foo/.git/info
  0B    foo/.git/objects
  0B    foo/.git/refs
ebg@taiyo(511)$ du -sh foo/.git/hooks/*
  4K    foo/.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
  4K    foo/.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
  4K    foo/.git/hooks/post-update.sample
  4K    foo/.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
  4K    foo/.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
  8K    foo/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
  4K    foo/.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
  4K    foo/.git/hooks/update.sample
```

Just perform `rm -f .git/hooks/*.sample` after you perform `git init`.  Bundle it in a shell function.  Of course, if you are really intent on axing the hooks you could do `sudo rm -f <path-to-git-install>/share/git-core/templates/hooks/*`

If you need to delete more than that you will enter into the realm of breaking git.

Comment: I probably did not express myself clearly. Sure I can delete these dirs, but I would rather not have the unneeded stuff to start with.

Comment: Then remove from .../share/git-core/...  (see above 'sudo' part.) The price of this discussion is already more than the cost of a bigger hard disk drive for you so you don't need to worry about kilobytes. :)

Comment: The code that generates the repos runs on boxes for which I don't have control outside of a specific directory.

Comment: Okay.  Your current approach is: "mkdir foo; cd foo; git init" and I'm suggesting "mkdir foo; cd foo; git init; rm -rf .git/hooks/*"

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Well, this is close to what I ended up doing: just filter out these dirs when compressing the repo before archiving it.

Answer (score 2):

By *“precious space”*, you are talking about those 14.1KiB example data that’s copied from the template? Sorry, but I don’t think you are wasting *anything* that way.

That being said, you could create a git alias to initialize an empty repository using a different template:

```
git config --global alias.init-minimal 'init --template path/to/template'
```

Other than that, there’s no way to specify a different template, *without* messing up the defaults located in `/usr/share/git-core/templates`.

Also, you probably won’t be able to prevent `/logs/` being created but the good thing about it is that’s relative to your repository size. So if you don’t have many commits, the log files will stay tiny.

Comment: 14.1KiB adds up pretty quickly when you start getting to hundred of millions entries.

Comment: If you have “hundred of millions” repositories, then you are probably not doing that on a workstation, but rather some server, right? Ever thought about virtualizing storage? That way you can stop thinking about duplicate files.

Comment: Virtualising would not help. This is not meant to create a bunch of repositories for users but as a way to track changes (and do more fancy stuff too) over independent group of files which are then packed and stored in the cloud.

Comment: "hundreds of millions" of repositories?  One for each 'User'.  Start with 1 and then 10; when you get to 1,000,000 you can start worrying about kilobytes per user.

Comment: I **already** have 100M "users", that's why I worry about it. :) Anyway, I am looking for something simple. Clearly if the cost of the solution is too high, I would not bother. But if it can be done easily I can save ~170GB which I can use for my prn collection ;)